# What does this iptables rule mean?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I found this iptables rule in some project I am working on:

`-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP`

What does this rule mean? How does it make the network more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be translated by "Drop every incoming segment that initialize a new TCP connection and where SYN control bit is not set among FIN,SYN,RST,ACK." (see [here](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html)).

A TCP segment used to initialize a connection should have the SYN control bit set so that rule is there to ensure that. Also, I think this rule avoid the use of different [port scan techniques](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html) involving segments without the SYN control bit set, like ACK scan. It silently drops the segment instead of sending an RST segment that could give information to a potential attacker.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeff. I wanted to say this before this question gets deleted by   crazy stackoverflow policy.

Comment: @codefx You're welcome. Next time you are asking for security reasons, I think it would be more relevant to do so in Information Security community :).